# How can I use tkinter to save and load images?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def save_state():
    try:
        save_dict = {}
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(7):
                idx = row * 7 + col
                label = placeholders[idx]
                if label in label_to_video_path:
                    video_path = label_to_video_path[label]
                    if isinstance(video_path, dict):
                        save_dict[idx] = {
                            'video': os.path.abspath(video_path['video']),
                            'thumbnail': os.path.abspath(video_path['thumbnail']),
                        }
                    elif isinstance(video_path, str):  # Handle case when video path is a string
                        save_dict[idx] = {
                            'video': os.path.abspath(video_path),
                            'thumbnail': '',  # Provide a default value for thumbnail path
                        }
                    else:
                        raise TypeError(f"Unexpected type for label_to_video_path[{label}]: {type(video_path)}")
        with open('state.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(save_dict, f)
        print("State saved successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception in save_state: {e}")

def load_state():
    try:
        with open('state.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            save_dict = pickle.load(f)

        for idx, paths in save_dict.items():
            if idx < len(placeholders):
                label = placeholders[idx]
                video_path = paths['video']
                thumbnail_path = paths['thumbnail']

                # Load and set the thumbnail image
                if thumbnail_path and os.path.exists(thumbnail_path):
                    image = Image.open(thumbnail_path)
                    image = image.resize((100, 100))
                    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                    photo_references.append(photo)  # Store reference to prevent garbage collection
                    label.config(image=photo, text=os.path.basename(video_path))
                    label_to_video_path[label] = {'video': video_path, 'thumbnail': thumbnail_path}

        print("State loaded successfully.")
        return save_dict  # Return the loaded state
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception in load_state: {e}")
        return None  # Return None if there was an error loading the state
```

this is the block

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarkSetchell    it is a basic youtube video downloader, it has a login to access and its a simple list of empty placeholders. when a video is downloaded, the thumbnail and the video fills the placeholder, and when clicked it opens the video. it should save when i exit the app but when i re open, the saved state is loaded and there is nothing in the ui. "no state loaded". i spent 11 hours trying to figure out the problem lol. that is not my full code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gts170017/2f76cf8f56126948d5d70bdbc9a97917#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Link to my full Code. ^^^

Comment: Note that `saved_state` inside `show_main_app()` is a local variable, not the global one.  You need to add `global saved_state` at the beginning of the function.  Also it is better to post a [mre] instead of a link to source file.